# It get crash when try to fetch the CNContact's Job Title and Profile Images

Tags: swift, uitableview, fetch, contacts, cncontact

I have a lot of troubleshooting these issues a few days ago.
Here the complete code,

You need to create 2 Files.

```
import Foundation
import Contacts

class contactsAspcts  {
    
    var contactOut: CNContact
    
    init(contactOut: CNContact) {
        self.contactOut = contactOut
        
    }
    
}
```

Then Create new files to create TableView Controller

```
    import UIKit


    private let cellId = "contactCell"

    class ViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    

    
   // the contacts array
    
    var allContacts = [contactsAspcts]()
    


    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupNavBar()
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        
        
        fetchData()
        
        searchBarUI()
    
        
    }

    
    
    func setupNavBar()  {
    
        navigationItem.title = "Your Contacts"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        
    }
    
    
    //MARK: SEARCH VIEW CONTROLLER - START
    
    var searchViewController: UISearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
     var searchResults: [contactsAspcts] = []
    
    
    func searchBarUI() {
           
           searchViewController.searchResultsUpdater = self
           
        searchViewController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
        
        searchViewController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        
        
           searchViewController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search contacts by family name"
           
           searchViewController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.yellow
           
           searchViewController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
           
           definesPresentationContext = true
           
           navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
           
           navigationItem.searchController = searchViewController
           
           
           
       }
    
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        
        let textToBeLowercased = searchViewController.searchBar.text?.lowercased()
        
        filtercontent(for: textToBeLowercased!)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    func filtercontent(for searchText: String) {
        
        searchResults = self.allContacts.filter({ (contact) -> Bool in
            
            return contact.contactOut.givenName.lowercased().range(of: searchText) != nil
            
            
        })
        
        
            
        
    }
    
    //MARK: SEARCH VIEW CONTROLLER - END
    
    
    
    

}

extension ViewController {
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headLabel = UILabel()
    
        headLabel.backgroundColor = .black
        
        return headLabel
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        
        return 10
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        
        return 1
        

    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    

        if searchViewController.isActive {
            
            return searchResults.count
            
        } else {
            
            return allContacts.count
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        
        if searchViewController.isActive {
            
            let cell = ContactShowCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
             
             cell.textLabel?.text = "\(searchResults[indexPath.row].contactOut.givenName)" + " \( searchResults[indexPath.row].contactOut.familyName)"
             
            
            /// This is crashed when fetching it
            // company
              cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(searchResults[indexPath.row].contactOut.jobTitle)" // crashed
           
            // Profile
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: searchResults[indexPath.row].contactOut.imageData!) // crashed
            
             return cell
            
            
        } else {
            
            let cell = ContactShowCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
             
             cell.textLabel?.text = "\(allContacts[indexPath.row].contactOut.familyName)" + " " + "\(allContacts[indexPath.row].contactOut.givenName)"
             
             cell.detailTextLabel?.text = (allContacts[indexPath.row].contactOut.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue)
             
            

             return cell
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let nextVC = DetailViewController()
        
        if searchViewController.isActive {
            
            nextVC.familyNamePassedOver = searchResults[indexPath.row].contactOut.familyName
            nextVC.givenNamePassedOver = searchResults[indexPath.row].contactOut.givenName
            
            
            if let phoneToPass = searchResults[indexPath.row].contactOut.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue {
                
                nextVC.phonenumberPassedOver = phoneToPass
                
            }
            
            
        } else {
            
            nextVC.familyNamePassedOver = allContacts[indexPath.row].contactOut.familyName
                   nextVC.givenNamePassedOver = allContacts[indexPath.row].contactOut.givenName
                   
                   
                   if let phoneToPass = allContacts[indexPath.row].contactOut.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue {
                       
                       nextVC.phonenumberPassedOver = phoneToPass
                       
                   }
        }
        
        
        
        
       
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
        
    }
    
   

    
}
    
    
    import Foundation
    import Contacts
    import UIKit
    
    extension ViewController {
        
        func fetchData() {
            
            let contactStore = CNContactStore()
            
            contactStore.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (accessGrant, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    
                    print("there is an error - \(error)")
                    
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "We need access to your contacts to display them", message: "Go to your settings and grant us permissions", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
                            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                            
                           
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    
                    return
                    
                } else {
                    
                    if accessGrant {
                        
                        print("access is granted")
                        
                        let fetchKeys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
                        
                        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: fetchKeys as [CNKeyDescriptor])
                        
                        do {
                            
                              
                            try  contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request) { (retrievedContact, stopPointer) in
                                  
                              
                                let contactObject = contactsAspcts(contactOut: retrievedContact)
                                
                                self.allContacts.append(contactObject)
                              
                              }
                        } catch let error {
                            
                            print("falied to enumerate" , error)
                            
                        }
    
                    } else {
                        
                        print("access is denied")
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
```

Note: I split the code of the search by using the if statement

> - search has shown a phone number
> - Not search show job title

It seems it successfully fetched a phone number (when it disable jobTitle and imageData from CNContacts) However, I enabled them and cause the crash app show up in console:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CNPropertyNotFetchedException', reason: 'A property was not requested when contact was fetched.'

I knew it one issues is this code!

```
         // Company
         cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(searchResults[indexPath.row].contactOut.jobTitle)" // crashed
       
        // Profile
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: searchResults[indexPath.row].contactOut.imageData!) // crashed
```

I have no idea. I have a lot of research on that issue with that crash, I have used CNContact which access the photo and Company (or else more) from Contacts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only reqwuested GivenName, firstName & Phone Number. You should also requests to fetch JobTitle and image. Your fetch keys should be like below,

```
let fetchKeys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactJobTitleKey, CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey]
```

You can check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/contact_keys) for all list of keys you can fetch for contacts. You can only use the fields from contacts you requesting here in fetchKeys otherwise app will crash with exception `CNPropertyNotFetchedException`

Comment: IT WORKED! THANKS! However, the company has fetched, but the Contact profile image is still crashed. Unsure why.

Comment: Update: Contact photo has updated new error: Unauthorized Keys. I never heard of it.

Comment: you can check for keys here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/contact_keys